# Providing 'this' via base constructor

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, generics, enumeration

I have a base class for enumerations that looks similar to the example below. My actual implementation covers far more such as explicit and implicit castings, reflection, flags and exception handling, but basically, it's just this:

```
public abstract class Enumeration<T> {

    // enum value
    protected readonly T _value;

    // collection of all values
    private static readonly HashSet<Enumeration<T>> _values
       = new HashSet<Enumeration<T>>();

    public T Value {
        get { return _value; }
    }

    // returns all values
    public static IEnumerable<Enumeration<T>> GetValues() {
        return _values.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I would like to have an enumeration of a certain type (may it be string, integer etc. I'm not so caged like with the usual C# enum), I can declare it this way:

```
public sealed class MyEnum : Enumeration<string> {

    public static readonly MyEnum EnumVal1 = new MyEnum("Val1!");
    public static readonly MyEnum EnumVal2 = new MyEnum("Val2!");
    public static readonly MyEnum EnumVal3 = new MyEnum("Val3!");

}
```

And make it either expandable or not by using a private or public constructor:

```
public MyEnum(string enumVal) : base(value: enumVal) {}
```

which passes the values to the base ctor:

```
protected Enumeration(T value) {
    _value = value;
    _values.Add(this);
}
```

This works fine for types like string, int, double etc. But what if I would like to enumerate complex objects?

```
public sealed class ComplexObj: Enumeration<ComplexObj> {

    public static readonly ComplexObj Val1 = new ComplexObj("val1", 455, null);

}
```

Here do the problems start, as I'm not able to pass the instanced objects to the base constructor:

```
public ComplexObj(string name, int someval, string another)
    : base(this) {} // doesn't work
```

And passing a new object to the constructor would lead to.. you know :)

```
: base(new ComplexObj(name, someval, another)) {} // lol
```

How could I solve this problem? Is there a way to pass the object itself to the base constructor?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "*doesn't work*"? Also, using object instances as enumeration-type structures is just plain wrong. Generally it's better to stick with a basic integer and if you need to add context to them use data annotations e.g. [DescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx).

Comment: @James It doesn't work because it's not valid to use the keyword 'this' in base() context. And: Why should something be 'plain' wrong that is being used as a practiced pattern in so many other languages e.g. Java...? The only thing that is plain wrong in my eyes is the C# enum. And the DescriptionAttribute is in no way straight-forward, you have to use resource consuming reflection just to get the values and it's also dangerous (lookup on fields with no attributes, enums with same description attribute values etc).

Comment: IMO it's plain wrong simply because it goes against the purpose of what an enum is supposed to be used for i.e. "*a distinct type consisting of a set of named constants called the enumerator list*" - object instances aren't named or constant. The `DescriptionAttribute` was just an example, you could roll your own attribute. Point being, if you describe the problem then maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: @James In my eyes, enums are just syntactic sugar because they are nothing else but classes. The constants are being compiled at runtime (like my instances) and the constant keys are being looked up using reflection, which is far worse than what I'm doing to get values IMO. Why I use this solution: I use those enums for parsing certain protocols where the values may contain special characters, spaces that are not declarable with enums. And I already described the problem: I can't pass the current class as parameter to the base class.

Comment: If I get you right, the problem is not to pass a this pointer to the base class constructor, but to parse protocols and get a specific object based on the protocols content?

Comment: @James My point is, enums and the pattern I use here are more or less exactly the same, so I don't see what's wrong with it. Did you ever decompiled mscorlib.dll and took a peak under the hood? .NET even caches all values in System.Enum.HashEntry classes. :/

Comment: @Atrotygma I never said what you were doing is wrong, I said using *object instances* as enumeration-type structures is wrong, and I still do. Also, it appears you are effectively re-inventing the wheel for little gain. "*Spaces that aren't declarable with enums*" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: @PVitt Yes and no. :) I've created libraries to parse various "plain-text" protocols, such as SDP, RTSP, SIP, RSCP and the solution I've got here what I found suits them most, because often you have values to parse in those protocols that are clearly enumerable (at this line, one of 6..7 values may occur there) but are undefined at the same time (own values are possible). So I can't use enums but I would like to offer an interface that tells the user what exactly belongs here, further than "string". With my solution, I can exactly do this. :)

Comment: @James You have to parse packet formats for media information in a protocol. Those can be either UDP, RTP AVP or RTP SAVP. So I can define an enumeration that would contain the following values: "UDP, RTP_AVP, RTP_SAVP". But the values in the protocol may look like this: "RTP/SAVP". How can I use my enum for parsing without using a) Attributes b) shaping the constant names to match the protocol values at runtime (replace, trim, tolower etc.) or c) declaring separate constants that contain the values like how they occur in the protocol? :)

Comment: @Atrotygma Why don't you just use a dictionary?

Comment: @PVitt Thought of that, would be perfect for parsing but not suitable for an interface where I would like to provide type that allows exactly a kind of value. :) And when I use a enum there together with a dictionary, I have to declare things twice (once in the enum and once to map the enum to the dictionary entry value for parsing.)

Comment: @Atrotygma "*How can I use my enum for parsing*" - that's exactly my point, you shouldn't. You should be using, for example, a factory method which you pass in your `enum` value which returns you the relevant parser to do the job. Like I said before, your approach just doesn't sit right with me, however, you appear to have solved your problem.

Comment: Could you please clarify the part with the interface and the one type you want to provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a kind of Enums that I wouldn't use, but if you would like to do so then this would be the solution:

```
public sealed class MyComplexObjEnum : Enumeration<ComplexObj>
{
    public MyComplexObjEnum(ComplexObj enumVal) : base( enumVal) { }
    public static readonly MyComplexObjEnum EnumVal1 = new MyComplexObjEnum(new ComplexObj("val1", 455, null));
    public static readonly MyComplexObjEnum EnumVal2 = new MyComplexObjEnum(new ComplexObj("val2", 456, null));
    public static readonly MyComplexObjEnum EnumVal3 = new MyComplexObjEnum(new ComplexObj("val3", 457, null));
}

public class ComplexObj 
{
    private readonly string _a;
    private readonly int _b;
    private readonly string _c;

    public ComplexObj(string a, int b, string c)
    {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
        _c = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution looks like the only way I could to this - so thank you. :) Glad you provided an actual answer instead of complaining how essential wrong is what I'm doing. (I have reasons, though).

Comment: @Atrotygma Trying to understand someone's problem and provide a solution is not *complaining*. Maybe if you were a bit more open minded you would see that...

Comment: @James I know that I'm not that open minded sometimes and, if you may noticed on my grammar, there's a certain language barrier between us that may complicate things. Anyway: 'using object instances as enumeration-type structures is just plain wrong' sounded like complaining to me. Sorry if I got that one wrong. :/

Comment: @Atrotygma nah that wasn't a complaint...it was a statement. At the end of the day it's your app and whatever solution you end up going with is what's right (to you). However, I was merely pointing out that as a *general* solution it's not the right way to do things. Regardless, you have a solution so good luck to you.